# TypeError in pandas when writing to mysql

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I have a tsv file which I want to upload to mysql server. In the table, there are some empty fields. So I fill them up with NULL. Here is the script:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io import sql
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect( host = HOSTNAME, user=USERNAME, passwd=PASSWD, db=DBNAME)
cursor = db.cursor()
df = pd.read_csv(FILENAME, sep='\t', index_col = False, dtype = unicode)
df1 = df.where((pd.notnull(df)), None)  ## To replace nan to NULL
df1.to_sql(con=db, name=TABLENAME, if_exists='replace', flavor='mysql')
db.close()
```

Here is the error message I get:

```
TypeError: Could not operate [None] with block values []
```

Could not find a solution. Could anybody help? Many thanks

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? (by the way, with the newest pandas, using mysql by specifying the 'flavor' keyword is deprecated, and you should use sqlalchemy engine instead)

Comment: I upgraded pandas, problem solved